# How to get specific part string from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables one is SifraArtikla

```
ID PuniNaziv
1  M-bus centrala tip MASTER PW60 sa adapterom
2  M-bus centrala tip MASTER PW120 sa adapterom
3  M-bus centrala tip MASTER PW250 sa adapterom
```

The second table ArtikalUsluge extend the SifraArtikla ID

```
Id ArtikalID
1  2
```

I need to get from PuniNaziv column 'PW60' if ArtikalID is 1 else if ID is 2 'PW120' else if ID is 3 'pw250'
I tried with if else statment but it didn't work. Can anyone give me some hints please.

```
DECLARE @OznakaCentrale NCHAR
SET @OznakaCentrale = 'PW%'
IF(@OznakaCentrale == SifreArtikala.PuniNaziv)
SELECT SifreArtikala.PuniNaziv AS NazivCentrale FROM SifreArtikala
INNER JOIN ArtikliUslugeNaloga ON ArtikliUslugeNaloga.Artikal1Id = SifreArtikala.Id
```

This is what I want to achive

```
Id NazivCentrale
    
 1  PW60
 2  PW120
 3  PW250
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the base string functions to identify the value as being in between the text `MASTER` and `sa`.  Then, join the two tables to restrict to only the `ID` values in the first table from whose text you want to extract.

```sql
SELECT
    sa.ID,
    SUBSTRING(sa.PuniNaziv,
              CHARINDEX('MASTER', sa.PuniNaziv) + 7,
              CHARINDEX('sa', sa.PuniNaziv) - CHARINDEX('MASTER', sa.PuniNaziv) - 8) AS P_ID
FROM SifraArtikla sa
INNER JOIN ArtikalUsluge au
    ON au.ArtikalID = sa.ID
```

### Demo

Comment: Hello, the answer is good for some ID but for some i get this error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Do you know what might be?

Comment: @loranni For strings not having both `MASTER` and `sa` you could get this error.  Use a `CASE` expression which checks for the presence of both these substrings and only uses the logic in my above answer should both substrings be present.